# Alternate for this mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table cinfo and astd. Below query takes to much time to returning result. Please tell the alternate query.

```
           SELECT cinfo.state, SUM(cstd.total_total_persons) as total, SUM(cstd.total_total_females) as girl  FROM cinfo 
           JOIN cstd WHERE cinfo.id = cstd.College_id
           GROUP BY cinfo.state
```

Comment: You should edit your question and show the schema of the tables (including indexes) and add the results of an EXPLAIN on the query. How many rows are in the two tables?

Answer (score 0):

First off, use an ON clause with your JOIN instead of the where.

Regarding performance, check your indexes on the two tables. Also, review what EXPLAIN shows for your query.

```
SELECT 
    cinfo.state, 
    SUM(cstd.total_total_persons) as total, 
    SUM(cstd.total_total_females) as girl
FROM cinfo 
JOIN cstd 
ON cinfo.id = cstd.College_id
GROUP BY cinfo.state
```

Comment: Sorry by mistake i forgot On clause. But your code also takes more time

Comment: Should take the same time. Did you check the EXPLAIN for the query? Did you check your indexes? Did you read my comment on your question?

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT cinfo.state, SUM(cstd.total_total_persons) as total, 
       SUM(cstd.total_total_females) as girl
FROM cinfo JOIN
     cstd
     ON cinfo.id = cstd.College_id
GROUP BY cinfo.state;
```

You can add an index on `cstd(College_id, total_total_persons, total_total_females)`.  There isn't much more you can do to optimize the query.